# How to make List content show through a bottom bar with material background

Tags: swiftui, blur, swiftui-list

I want the list content to show through the bottom bar like it does with the top navigation bar, creating the blur effect. I can do it with a `ZStack` instead of `VStack` and some padding on the last element of the list, but then I have to know the exact height of the bottom bar, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way to do it?

[image: Bottom bar needs to blur]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                List(1...30, id:\.self) { i in
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.random)
                        .frame(height: 36)
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                Text("Bottom bar")
                    .font(.title)
                    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(.bar)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Some Nav Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        
    }
}

extension Color {
    static var random: Color {
        return Color(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you need `.ultraThinMaterial`

Comment: @Asperi Just found out `.bar` exactly matches system bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `ZStack` instead of `VStack`, like

```
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {         // << here !!
            List(1...30, id:\.self) { i in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.random)
                    .frame(height: 36)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            Text("Bottom bar")
                .font(.title)
                .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(.regularMaterial)
        }
```

*Note: most probably you will need to add footer to the list of same height as your bar, so during scrolling to the bottom last items will be visible.*

Comment: I'd rather not use padding or a footer with a hard coded height if possible, if the user increases font size it could end up being off

Comment: I did not say you have to *hardcode* it, I said use the same - there are several ways to do that, eg. use same view or calculate dynamically... there is examples on stackoverflow for each.

Comment: Ugly to play with passing PreferenceKeys around but it works